# How can I disable a UISegmentedControl?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uisegmentedcontrol

I have the following UISegmentedControl, which I want to be disabled:

```
-(void)displayCheckMark
{
    titleSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil];
    [titleSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"symbolbg.png"] atIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [titleSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inwatchlist.png"] atIndex:1 animated:YES];
    [titleSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(titleBarButtonChanged:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    titleSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    titleSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(100,0,100,30);
    titleSegmentedControl.momentary = YES;
    titleSegmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleSegmentedControl;

    [titleSegmentedControl setWidth:60 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [titleSegmentedControl setTitle:symbol forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [titleSegmentedControl setWidth:30 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [titleSegmentedControl setEnabled:NO];
}
```

I don't have it enabled anywhere in the code. Yet I can still click on it, and it will perform the action in titleBarButtonChanged:

How can I make sure it can't be clicked?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using:

```
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment;
```

or

```
titleSegmentedControl.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 3):

Within `titleBarButtonChanged:(id)sender` add:

```
if(!sender.enabled) return;
```